# Como se encuadra un panel dentro de un contenedor?

Tags: java

Tengo el `frame` principal y una clase `panel`, lo que quiero es hacer varias clases `panel` e ir poniéndolas en el recuadro. El `frame` principal tiene un `panel` ya de serie e iría cambiando. Mi problema es que, va todo bien pero el contenedor (fondo rojo) no se ajusta al `panel` (verde).

Este es mi código:

```
{
    MenuOperaciones Menu = new MenuOperaciones();
    contenedor = panel0;
    contenedor.removeAll();
    contenedor.setBackground(Color.red);
    Menu.setSize(panel0.getSize());
    Menu.setBounds(panel0.getBounds());

    contenedor.add(Menu);
    contenedor.repaint();
    contenedor.validate();
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: creo que le falta el contenedor.pack()

Comment: no se a que te refieres escribo eso y no soporta el método pack el contenedor,

Comment: MI error. Creía que estabas agregando a un JFrame, pero veo que estás agregando a un panel.

Comment: MenuOperaciones que clase es? o sea que exitende? y contenedor tampoco especificas que tipo de clase es. No puedo ver que tipo de componentes son.

Comment: MenuOperaciones es una clase Jpanel, CONTENEDOR ES UN OBJETO DE LA CLASE CONTAINER

Comment: Quiero hacer un programa que vaya cambiando de pantalla, en este caso es un cajero automático si sabes de alguna forma mejor de hacer el cambio de una pantalla a otra, es decir al pulsar un botón cambie a otra y asi sucesivamente

Comment: Puede ser con el CardLayout, así puedes crear todos los menus y solamente cambiar el panel que requieres. ¿haz usado ese layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te pongo un ejemplo para usarlo con java.awt.CardLayout.

```
JPanel contenedor = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
JPanel menu1 = new JPanel(); // configuramos este panel
JPanel menu2 = new JPanel(); //configuramos...

contenedor.add(menu1, "menu1");
contenedor.add(menu2, "menu2");
```

Aquí estas agregando los diferentes páneles que puedes mostrar en el contenedor, y para seleccionar uno, o para mostrar uno, requiere especificar cual quieres mostrar. Lo haces en el método show, que pongo abajo:

luego en donde escuchas a los botones:

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
    ....
    String menuSelectionado = ?? // menu1 o menu2 por ejemplo       

    java.awt.CardLayout layout = (java.awt.CardLayout)contenedor.getLayout());
    layout.show(contenedor, menuSeleccionado); //aquí especificas cual quieres mostrar en el contenedor.
```

}